# Protractor (5.2.2) - element.all(by.css('')).click() stopped working suddenly from Dec 17th

Tags: npm, protractor

We are using Protractor (5.2.2), chrome based functional testing. Please see the configuration information.

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
getPageTimeout: 1000,
allScriptsTimeout: 3000,
framework: 'custom',
verbose:'true',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('../../node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework'),
ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['--disable-web-security'],
        'mobileEmulation': {
            'deviceName': 'Nexus 6'
        }
    }
}
```

Our test scripts where working from past 4 months without any issue, suddenly from Dec 17th all the `element.all(by.css('')).click()` stopped working. When it tries to execute this method after some time I could see browser right-click menu instead of element click.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: First shot in the dark - check if your Chrome, ChromeDriver, Protractor versions are the latest and up to date. Sounds really like as some sort of a compatibility issue.

Comment: Also, are there any errors when you execute your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a work around by pointing the chromeOptions to user-agent instead of mobileEmulation, the test script worked fine.

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4']         
    }
},

    and set the browser size - browser.manage().window().setSize(375, 667);
```

Comment: You should be able to set the window size through the `args` as well, passing in addition `, 'window-size=375,667'`